# Can you always have a particular character amongst your starting squad?

Tags: xcom-2

Is there a way to ensure that one (or more) of your starting troops is a particular character from your character pool?

Comment: Not without a mod.I don't think. Characters in the character pool are more likely to be chosen though.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, by having 4 or fewer characters in your character pool and turning on the "Only characters from Character Pool" option.**  This will guarantee that they are chosen for Operation Gatecrasher.  However, your other recruits will not be from the character pool, making this approach limited.